# How can pscp filepath with spaces?

Tags: pscp

I have this file:

> C:\Documents and Settings\tc\My
>   Documents\Downloads\ee_server_wizard.zip

and I am trying to upload it to server via pscp like this:

```
pscp C:\Documents and Settings\tc\My Documents\Downloads\ee_server_wizard.zip root@mydomain.com:/var/www/
```

But it has problem with the spaces. Which is the right syntax?

Thanks in advance

PS: I could just move it to a path with no spaces but I want to know the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply put quotes around it. (That has nothing to do with pscp, but is a Windows and Unix-like shell thing; remember that the escape rules are different though.)

```
pscp "a b" foo@bar:
```